# AppDelegate presents views twice

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I'm implementing quick-actions for my app and for that I need to present viewcontrollers from the app delegate. I use code like this:

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"MyControllerID") as! MyController
        let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)

        if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
            var currentController = rootViewController
            while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
                currentController = presentedController
            }
            currentController.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

If the app is in background and the quickaction is clicked everything works fine, but if the app hasn't been started yet and the quick-action gets clicked the view is presented twice.

What am I doing wrong here?

// Edit 1: This code is in a function and the function is called in `applicationDidBecomeActive`
In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I check if the app was launched via Quick-Actions like this:

```
if let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {

        launchedShortcutItem = shortcutItem
    }
```

The `launchedShortcutItem` is a variable:

```
var launchedShortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem?
```

// Edit 2: For those who don't know what I mean by "Quick-Actions" here are the Apple Pages for them: [Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/home-screen-actions/), [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ApplicationShortcuts/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: In your storyboard, don't you have an entry point set on the view controller that's being presented twice ?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me . (a) you didn't mention where you put this code exactly in the app delegate , (b) ' quick-actions' what is this actually ? describe the goal you want to achieve , I hope I can help you as i did something like this recently , where a view controller pop up every-time the app come to foreground

Comment: @Roy I added information in my question.

Comment: @GIJOW I don't have an entry point on that view controller.

Comment: thank you @LarsGvB your question looks perfect now !